# swift retain cycle in function

Tags: swift, function, cycle, retain

I'd like to ask if retain cycle happens in this situation:

```
func someFunc() {
    var aVar = SomeObj()
    funcWithClosure(something, completionHandler: { _ -> Void in
        aVar = SomeObj() // new
    })
}
```

In this case, I refer back to aVar from the closure. I just wonder if this creates a retain cycle. If true, should I fix by:

```
func someFunc() {
    var aVar = SomeObj()
    funcWithClosure(something, completionHandler: { [weak aVar] _ -> Void in
        aVar = SomeObj() // new
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to expand on your question, you *would* get a retain cycle if `aVar` strongly references the closure. For example:

```
func someFunc() {
    var aVar = SomeObj()
    aVar.funcWithClosure(something, completionHandler: {
        doSomethingWith(aVar)
    }
}
```

`aVar` strongly references the closure because it calls the function, and the closure strongly references `aVar` because it uses the variable in its body. To break the cycle, you could create a weak reference to `aVar` **outside** the closure, like this:

```
func someFunc() {
    var aVar = SomeObj()
    weak var weakVar = aVar
    aVar.funcWithClosure(something, completionHandler: {
        if let weakVar = weakVar {
             doSomethingWith(weakVar)
        }
    }
}
```

`weakVar` references `aVar`, so you use it in the place of `aVar`. And it references it weakly, so when `aVar` goes out of scope (when the function completes), its ref count can become zero. Inside the closure, since `weakVar` is a weak var, need to unwrap it somehow before using.

In your question, you proposed adding `[weak aVar]` to the closure's capture list, which I don't believe would work.

EDIT: fixed unwrapping `weakVar` as `var`, which is a keyword.

Answer (score 5):

No, it doesn't. The closure holds a strong reference to `aVar`, but `aVar` doesn't hold a reference to the closure, so there is no cycle.

Comment: Thanks, Ole. So if I add `[weak aVar]`, there is still nothing wrong? Just redendant. Right?

Comment: No, you can't generally say that. In your specific code sample it might work because you're not doing anything with the objects you assign to `aVar`. But your code sample doesn't make a lot of sense anyway. An object gets deallocated when no strong reference to it exists, so it makes a big difference whether you use `weak` or not.